# Puppet missing Facter environment variables

Tags: puppet, facter

Any environment variable prefixed with "FACTER_" is automatically added to the facter collection. I've successfully added a "FACTER_" environment variable it is indeed showing up in the facter -p list, so it should be able to be used by puppet...

The problem, though, is in my .pp file the variable name that should be set to the FACTER_ value is empty (or non existant)

Is there something else I need to do to get FACTER_ variables into puppet variables?

Cheers

Comment: How are you running puppet?

Comment: I.e., are you sure that the `FACTER_...` variable is part of the **agent**'s environment? You might wish to inspect `/proc/<pid>/environ` to make sure.

Comment: That is it. If I run "sudo facter" I don't get my custom FACTER_ facts. Similarly, if I run "sudo -E puppet agent -t" it works and puppet creates the correct FACTER_ variables. How do I get puppet to include these env variables?

Comment: Chris - running puppet as a service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely setting up the system so that the `FACTER_` variables are available in interactive shells. This is not sensible if you want your background agent to respect them.

I can see two direct approaches:

1. Modify your initscript or its configuration to set the appropriate environment variables.
2. Forego the approach entirely and use `/etc/facter/facts.d` instead.

I would advise towards the latter.

Comment: Yep, I went with 2. Thanks.

Comment: how could you do this with `kitchen-puppet`? https://github.com/neillturner/puppet_repo